# Does systemLayoutSizeFittingSize: require setNeedsLayout & layoutIfNeeded before it?

Tags: uiview, autolayout

A number of S.O. questions show an autolayout technique to determine the minimum size required by a view requires to fulfil its constraints: `[header systemLayoutSizeFittingSize: UILayoutFittingCompressedSize]`

Before making the `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:` call, all the examples I've seen force a layout update, like this:

```
[view setNeedsLayout];
[view layoutIfNeeded];
CGFloat height = [view systemLayoutSizeFittingSize: UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;
```

I'd like to know when this is actually necessary as it seems sprinkled in as a ritual seasoning: I'd like to understand why I'm making calls, rather than doing it for luck!

I've just used `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:` in some code where I selectively update a view that's a `UITableView` instance's `tableViewHeader` (not section header), then resize it. It seems to work fine without the extra calls. I have this in my `viewDidLoad`:

```
{
    // Remove the view that we don't want.
    [self.autoPopulateView removeFromSuperview];

    // Resize the table's header view now the unwanted view is removed.
    UIView *const header = self.tableView.tableHeaderView;

    // Don't explicitly layout.
    // [header setNeedsLayout];
    // [header layoutIfNeeded];

    CGFloat height = [header systemLayoutSizeFittingSize: UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;
    CGRect frame = header.frame;
    frame.size.height = height;
    header.frame = frame;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I'm investigating the same thing, ever reached a conclusion? Thanks!

Comment: :-) No! I'm pretty sure that I read something related, but I can't find it now. I thought about putting a bounty on it, but I'm not sure that I care about it quite that much. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

There definitely shouldn't be a need to make either of those calls prior to calling systemLayoutSizeFittingSize. As long as all your constraints are in place, you shouldn't need to do anything else.

In fact, forcing a layout pass beforehand is potentially detrimental from a performance standpoint, and I would argue that doing so is not only unnecessary, but actually harmful.

Comment: Every solution i have seen on SO works that way. Do you happen to know another way to achieve it? (without calling layoutIfNeeded)

Comment: yeah, don't call layoutIfNeeded? The original question said as much: "It seems to work fine without the extra calls". So the question I would ask is: are you seeing somewhere where it *is* needed to return the correct values, and if so, can you provide more details?

Comment: Yes. In the case of table view cells and collection view cells. It seems like it is done because there is no width anchor specified for the cell. I think i now understand how this method works.

Answer (score 0):

it definately seems like `layoutIfNeeded` is a catch-all response to seeing inconsistencies of height calculations when using `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize` - the problem is that the value is very difficult to debug when it's incorrect

In my experience you need to call `layoutIfNeeded` whenever your target view has updated the constraints in code, for example changing a constant, adding, removing a constraint. Calling `setNeedsLayout` or `setNeedsUpdateConstraints` does not work (shrug)